# How to customize label from Netdata in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus, influxdb, graphite

I'm using netdata to monitor my instance and containers.
I use prometheus to query the data and I use influxDB to store it

Netdata creates long chart name and I would like to reduce them to make my dashboard clearer.
I want the label to be the actual name of the containers :

- nginx
- grafana
- netdata
- ...

But what I get is `cgroup_<container_name>.<metric_name>`

[image: dashboard grafana]

I can see that there is a [pull request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/6627) about legend formatting since 2016 but I was wondering if there is another solution.

Maybe directly from Netdata? Or maybe using another tool such as Graphite instead of Prometheus?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not using prometheus so i can't help you but i'm on graphite. With graphite u can use alias() function to display shorter name.